# How to echo string inside other string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the string `base` to appear along with the design,

The current code does not work - on the page itself the text appears as:

> (base) //red color

It is supposed to be:

> http://mywebsite.com //red color

Code:

```
var base = window.location;
str = '<p><b style="color:red;">(base)</b></p>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = '<p><b style="color:red;">(' + base + ')</b></p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.
>   You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with
>   them.

It's enclosed by the back-tick (` `) character instead of double or single quotes.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var base = window.location;
var str = `<p><b style="color:red;">${base}</b></p>`
$('body').html(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: IE11 (which is still kinda supported) does not like these: https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals, so I'd probably just stick to the good old version of `' + var + '`